# Jumping on the x axis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

How can I make jumps from month to month if jump is always fixed to the x axis? 
Obviously not all months have the same days, they have the same days. Is there any way to tell Highcharts the jump is a certain month and another the next?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`xAxis.setExtremes(min, max)`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes).

For example:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes( Date.UTC(2011, 0, 1), Date.UTC(2011, 1, 1) ); //zoom in Jan 01-Feb 01)
```